# how can i make a drop down menu using lists

Tags: html, css, list, hover, dropdown

This is my html and css. I want to make a drop down menu on hover but i cannot call the respective class. If anyone can help me with this. I would really appreciate it. and i don't want to use javascript. I only want the solution in css. P.S: I am using
a template for my website .I just need help in calling the header class.

```css
#navigation .navbar {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.952941);
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 0px 3px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#navigation .navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navigation .navbar-brand h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
  padding: 0 1px;
}

#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  margin-top: 28px
}

#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
  color: #43484E;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all .9s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all .9s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all .9s ease 0s;
  transition: all .9s ease 0s;
  padding: 6px 15px;
}

#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a,
#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a:focus,
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ce181e;
}
```

```html
<header id="navigation">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="scroll active"><a href="#navigation">About Us</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">Academics</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Admissions</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#our-team">Campuses</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Student Life</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#clients">News & events</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Careers</a></li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/navbar-->
</header>
<!--/#navigation-->
```

code

Comment: The toggle is not able to access the navigation with CSS using your current markup. Can you restructure your HTML?

Comment: will restructuring it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H! Using your initial setup a simple css-only dropdown menu can be made by placing a nested `ul` with options into an `li` and adding these styles:

```
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
    list-style: none;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li ul:hover li {
    display: block;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```css
#navigation .navbar {
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.952941);
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 0px 3px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

#navigation .navbar-toggle{
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navigation .navbar-brand h1{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right {
 margin-top:28px
}
/* added styles start */
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
    list-style: none;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li ul li:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li ul:hover li {
    display: block;
}
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li {
 padding: 5px;
}
/* added styles end */
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a {
 color: #43484E;
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-transition: all .9s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all .9s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all .9s ease 0s;
 transition: all .9s ease 0s;
 padding: 6px 15px;
}

#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  .active  a,  
#navigation .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav  .active  a:focus, 
#navigation .navbar-nav.navbar-right li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #ce181e;
}
```

```html
<header id="navigation"> 
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="banner"> 
   <div class="container"> 
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
     </button> 
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></h1></a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> 
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#about-us">Academics</a></li> 
    <li class="scroll active">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#navigation">About Us0</a></li>
                <li><a href="#navigation">About Us1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#navigation">About Us2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#navigation">About Us3</a></li>
            </ul>
           </li> 
     <li class="scroll"><a href="#services">Admissions</a></li> 
     <li class="scroll"><a href="#our-team">Campuses</a></li> 
     <li class="scroll"><a href="#portfolio">Student Life</a></li> 
     <li class="scroll"><a href="#clients">News & events</a></li> 
     <li class="scroll"><a href="#blog">Careers</a></li> 
     <li class="scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div><!--/navbar--> 
 </header> <!--/#navigation-->
```

So, I hope you got the idea and now you can play around to achieve what you want. You may check some material on [positioning](https://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/detailed-css-positioning/) needed to create more complex layouts.